# In javascript how to split a group of sentence using regular expression

Tags: javascript

```
<object width="480" height="385">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/_b9_WUcxF1I?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/_b9_WUcxF1I?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

using this paragraph, i want **http://www.youtube.com/v/_b9_WUcxF1I?fs=1&amp** only (url). how can i split or get the value using regular expreesion in javascript.

Comment: You want to split sentences or you want to find URLs?  If finding URLs is all you're doing, you don't need to identify them in sentences first.  Just use any premade regular expression online for finding URLs.

Comment: If you are not sure that the URL is valid, do what Neil said. It it has already been validated and you just need to retrive it in a string, you can look for a simplier regular expression like : 'http://.*\b'

Comment: I don't understand: http://www.youtube.com/v/_b9_WUcxF1I?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US is the url. What you point (http://www.youtube.com/v/_b9_WUcxF1I?fs=1&amp) is an uncomplete one, since &amp; is the html entity for the amperstamp (&) character. So the actual url is http://www.youtube.com/v/_b9_WUcxF1I?fs=1&hl=en_US ...

Comment: yes i want http://www.youtube.com/v/_b9_WUcxF1I?fs=1&amp; with &amp also

Answer (score 0):

here's one for you:

```
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
```